# MySQL fetch column value of particular row

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch a particular column value of a particular row using php in mysql.

For example if I want to fetch column2 value in row2, I tried using:

```
$qry = mysql_query("SELECT * from $table");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($qry);
$result = $data[1];
```

but this always returns only the first row value.

Comment: What defines row 2? There must be an ORDER BY

Comment: [mysql_fetch_row](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)() fetches one row each time you call it and returns FALSE when there are no rows left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Column2
FROM $table
ORDER BY Something
LIMIT 1,1;
```

Or, if you know the key of the row

```
SELECT Column2
FROM $table
WHERE Key = Something
-- Optional: if you want 2nd after filtering
-- ORDER BY Something
-- LIMIT 1,1;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select COLUMNNAME from TABLENAME where ROWELEMENT="SOME_VALUE";
```

This should be your sql query..
You will need to access the value of that element using

```
$result['COLUMNNAME']
```

Complete code should look like this.

```
$query="select COLUMNNAME from TABLENAME where ROWELEMENT='SOME_VALUE'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$result=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$columnvalue=$result['COLUMNNAME'];
```

Its bcoz mysql_query returns the result in an associative array form.
After the above code, You can access all elements like this.

```
$columnname[$index];
```

This will return the first value,

According to your question, You will need to first get the column values in a saperate array, and then access it using your index value..